# Delete a subarray in an array in JavaScript using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-splice

I need to delete a subarray if it has a particular element.

```
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] === elem) {
        arr.splice(i--, 1);
        newArr = [...arr]
      }
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 19));
```

The code above works fine if the element is found just once (for ex. 19). But if I try number 3, I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that once you've `splice`d an item out of the array, your program continues iterating over the rest of the removed inner array as if it still existed. In the case of `3` as your target, every single inner array is removed because they all contain a `3`. At the final removal, you detect a `3` at index `1` of the inner array and `splice` the last inner array. On the next iteration of the loop, the program crashes attempting to index into `[0][2]` in the empty array `[]`.

The solution is to add a `break` statement as follows; this will abort further inspection of a removed array:

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] === elem) {
        arr.splice(i--, 1);
        newArr = [...arr]
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Having said that, there are many simpler approaches you can take; for example, using `array.filter()`, which selects elements based on the truth value returned by its argument function:

```js
const filteredArray = (a, target) => a.filter(e => !e.includes(target));

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 19));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the solution to the code i provided. :) Of course I will go with filter.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is succinct enough you probably don't need a separate function:

```js
let array = [[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]]
let filtered = array.filter(item => !item.includes(19));
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Array.filter()

```js
function filteredArray(arr, skip) {
  return arr.filter(function(sub) {
    return -1 === sub.indexOf(skip);
  });
}

var mixed = [[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 2], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]];
console.log(filteredArray(mixed, 19));
console.log(filteredArray(mixed, 3));
```

Comment: better logic employed here

Comment: Arvind, thanks for the nice solution and concise code.